# Conflicts due to case differences during get latest even though developers have not changed anything

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, conflict

I am using TFS 2012 express. When i try to use get latest version I get so many conflicts(more than 250). When I compare it i found that almost most of the conflicts are due to Case differences. Some times i do i get valid conflicts and which can be manipulated using merge tool. But comparing this lot number of conflicts(more than 250) is very difficult to me. For example in below image you can see changes like MsfgTemp and MSFgtemp(this kind of case differences) . I do get lot of this kind of differences(one more i got is Val and val) . No one has made any changes to those lines actually. But still conflicts are shown. Why this kind of conflicts I get during get latest version? How to solve this?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have found some thing interesting after some research on it. I did several steps to find reason for it. When i was doing it no other user in my team was using TFS or changing anything.

The server has MsfgTemp(in so many lines of code).

I created new workspace and without changing anything compared with server version. As expected no difference found .

Now I changed some lines of code and saved the project.

Now when I see difference I found lot of differences. All changes are like MsfgTemp and MSFgtemp. Another was val and Val .

So it is sure that the reason is not some one changed or anything else. While saving project something causes these changes. My project is of VB6. I edit projects using Microsoft  Visual basic 6.0 only.

So now what may be the reason for this kind of difference and how it can be solved?

Comment: No one changed those lines *by hand*, but maybe some tool changed the casing to match the declared version? Can you check the history of that file to see when the change appeared?

Comment: @HansKesting I have edited my question with what test i have done to check the reason for this difference. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the TFS file history or use the [annotate option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) to see who changed those lines and when they were changed.

Since TFS only stores the files it doesn't change the contents you should first find out who checked in the changes and that will lead you to the how and why it changed.

**NOTE:** from looking at the little bit of code you posted in the example **the same variable name is used two lines above** in both files **without conflict**.

```
TempVar = MSFgtemp.TextMatrix(i, TaxDeductedCol)
```

the conflict your are noticing just two lines later is for a very similarly named variable  but I believe this one is different since it is declared inside the loop, so this might be a bug fix with a poorly named temp variable inside the loop...

```
TempVar = MsfgTemp.TextMatrix(i, ArrAddColNum(k))
```

Comment: I have edited my question with what test i have done to check the reason for this difference. Please check it.

Comment: You might try resetting your VB [environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx)
Apparently Visual Studio can be configured via the Tools->Options settings to apply auto replacement of items. I do not have this on my system nor do I use VB, so I cannot speak to having seen this issue.